# Parsing SAS datetime to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, sas

I'm loading a CSV that was produced with SAS into a pandas DataFrame. In order to parse the SAS times I created a parser function like this:

```
def parse_date(d):
    try:
        date = dt.timedelta(seconds=int(d)) + dt.datetime(1960, 1, 1)
        return date
    except ValueError:
        print("There was a problem parsing.")
```

Now, when I pass this function a SAS datetime, like the first value in one of my date columns, it gives me exactly the output that I want:

```
parse_date(1652745600)
Out[9]: datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 16, 0, 0)
```

However, when I pass the function as date_parser to `pd.read_csv()`, I get value errors, like so:

```
def get_ods_reader():
    ods_reader = pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv", 
                             chunksize=200000, parse_dates=[6, 9, 10, 16],
                             dtype={"account_nbr": object, "REPOSSESSION_STATUS_CD": object},
                             converters={"repossession_ind": parse_int},
                             date_parser=parse_date)
    return ods_reader

# Getting the data types of all columns
chunk_dtypes = []
for chunk in get_ods_reader():
    print(chunk.head(5))
    chunk_dtypes.append(chunk.dtypes)

Out[10]:
There was a problem parsing.
There was a problem parsing.
There was a problem parsing.
There was a problem parsing.
There was a problem parsing.
There was a problem parsing.
There was a problem parsing.
...
```

Comment: Are you sure your `parse_dates` parameter hits the correct indices? Without data is quite impossible to debug your issue.

Comment: Positive the indeces are correct:`chunk.columns[[6, 9, 10, 16]]
Out[20]: 
Index(['purchase_dt', 'EARLIEST_UNPAID_DUE_DT', 'last_payment_dt',
       'repossession_dt'],
      dtype='object')`

Comment: Could it be because of missing values? How would I go about this then, first convert missing values to NaT on import and only convert to datetime after import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try editing you except to:

```
def parse_date(d):
    try:
        date = dt.timedelta(seconds=int(d)) + dt.datetime(1960, 1, 1)
        return date
    except ValueError:
        return pd.NaT
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. However, when I append the chunks to an h5 file, I now get the following error: "too many timezones in this block, create separate "

TypeError: too many timezones in this block, create separate data columns

Comment: There is data for 13 different countries in that file, so I guess that's "too many timezones". If I wanted to assign the records to different h5 file, depending on the country, I'd have to iterate through each row separately. It would probably be faster to import without date conversion, split the data into different files, and then do the date conversion, right?

Comment: Or you can filter the file by country and save to different files each slice.

Comment: Ho can I filter by country on read_csv? I'm reading in chunks of 200000 rows each and each chunk can contain any number of countries. Is there a way to read in only the rows that are from a certain country? I just looked at the documentation and couldn't find an option for this.

Comment: No, but you can split your chunk into data per country and each time you read a chunk add country data into designated df.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for so many questions, I hope this will be the last one. Just wondering how you would do this practically. I store the chunks to disk like so: with pd.HDFStore("ods_07.h5") as store:
    for chunk in get_ods_reader():
        chunk.to_hdf(store, "ods", append=True, format="t", data_columns=True)

My first thought would be a list of all countries, loop though the list for each chunk and change the key of the h5 file depending on the country. Is that how you would do it?

Comment: I have asked a separate question, I think this is out of scope for this question. Thanks for your help.